# flex-wrap doesn't work. How do i fix this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn flexbox (it's my day 1) and i don't quite understand it. Here's the code:

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="box left-box">1</div>
    <div class="box left-box">2</div>
    <div class="box left-box">3</div>
    <div class="box left-box">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="box right-side">5</div>
    <div class="box right-side">6</div>
    <div class="box right-side">7</div>
    <div class="box right-side">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 22px red solid;
}
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.right-side{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.left-side{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

i added wrap on every rule because it wasn't working (and still doesn't). Could you please tell me what is (are) my mystake(s)?

[image]

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CornelRaiu just so it doesn't go outside the border and takes the space right next to "1" and "2". I'm really a newbie

Comment: @KnowNothing exactly as in `right-side`?

Comment: @001 no i want it to be a "column".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a max-height to the `.box` container which is `.left-side`.

I also increased the height of your `.container` because otherwise you would have the boxes on the left in one line. The total height of a `.box` is the height + the border which for you is 54px. 54 + 54 would be 108 and it would wrap again resulting in only 1 line because the container originally had 100px height.

**Extra tip**
To make sure the boxes have exactly the height you need and include the border in the box height you have to use `box-sizing: border-box` on the `.box` elements

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 22px red solid;
}
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.right-side{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.left-side{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="box left-box">1</div>
    <div class="box left-box">2</div>
    <div class="box left-box">3</div>
    <div class="box left-box">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="box right-side">5</div>
    <div class="box right-side">6</div>
    <div class="box right-side">7</div>
    <div class="box right-side">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much for your time and answer. If it won't bother you i'd like to ask another (and last) question. Is it good that i made <div class="right-side"> and <div class"left-side"> to separate them and take 2 different places or there's a better way to do it?

Comment: @KnowNothing this question is very vague. It is good in some cases, could be done better in others. I can not reply to that question with a yes or no

Comment: @KnowNothing if my answer helped you, make sure you mark it as accepted so that others would know it is a useful solution.

Comment: I meant in this case, but i got i - the right answer would be = "it depends". Thanks again for your help and for the courtesy with a newbie. Have a very good day!